# WildFly 12.0.0.Final + Weld 3.0.3.Final - How to use CDI 2.0?

Tags: wildfly, cdi, cdi-2.0

On the Weld.org page, it says for WildFly 12.0.0.Final:

> WildFly 12.0.0.Final  Weld 3.0.3.Final CDI 1.2  and CDI 2.0   (opt-in
>   via property)

I can't see how to "opt-in via property"?

Comment: Read the links in the your websockets questions.... please...

Comment: Besides, it's literally first link to come up when you Google it (in this one case it's a shame you cannot post LMGTFY links on SO)...

Comment: I am running WildFly 12 with '-Dee8.preview.mode=true'. So that enables CDI 2.0. I must have missed it in the articles. Thank you for constructive comments, you could have patronised me even more by sharing the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is look at WildFly site, because you need to run WildFly in so called "EE8 preview" mode in order to have certain EE 8 techs (CDI 2.0 including) enabled.
Namely [this article](http://wildfly.org/news/2018/02/28/WildFly12-Final-Released/) says it all:

> By default WildFly 12 launches in EE7 mode. In order to use these new capabilities you have to enable EE8 preview mode. This can be accomplished by passing the ee8.preview.mode property during startup:
>
> `./standalone.sh -Dee8.preview.mode=true`

There are other options, such as CLI config or modifying the standalone config file. Take a glance at the article to see how that is achieved.

Comment: Thanks. I am running WildFly 12 with '-Dee8.preview.mode=true'. So that enables CDI 2.0. I will re-read!